# Jenkins not taking provided Gmail credentials instead of that it is taking System user

Tags: jenkins, smtp, jenkins-email-ext

In email configuration, Jenkins NOT taking smtp gmail credentials and it is considering System user credentials.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V8g2c.png)

Please help me, what is the reason for this issue.
Test configuration for email notification is working fine but while executing Jobs, email is not getting.

I have user 2 factor verification in Gmail and user passCode here. This is set in global level under Manage Jenkins

Error is because of user= 'system user' and password= null

Message is as below after execution of a job

DEBUG: getProvider() returning jakarta.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle]
DEBUG SMTP: need username and password for authentication
DEBUG SMTP: protocolConnect returning false, host=smpt.gmail.com, user=UC241143, password=
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "smpt.gmail.com", port 465, isSSL false
MailConnectException message: Couldn't connect to host, port: smpt.gmail.com, 465; timeout 60000
Next UnknownHostException message: smpt.gmail.com
Finished: SUCCESS